# What is an Aerious Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Aerious Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Aerious Words™ | Not Aerious Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE | COUNTER |
| CHAIR | SEAT |
| ENGLISH | CHINESE |
| FACETIOUS | MISCHIEVOUS |
| TWENTY-SIX | TWENTY-FIVE |
| LESSON | LECTURE |
| ADBLOCK PLUS | UBLOCK ORIGIN |
| BOOK | READ |
| WATER | COFFEE |
| PHOTOSHOP | ILLUSTRATOR |

CSV Version:

```
Aerious Words™,Not Aerious Words™
TABLE,COUNTER
CHAIR,SEAT
ENGLISH,CHINESE
FACETIOUS,MISCHIEVOUS
TWENTY-SIX,TWENTY-FIVE
LESSON,LECTURE
ADBLOCK PLUS,UBLOCK ORIGIN
BOOK,READ
WATER,COFFEE
PHOTOSHOP,ILLUSTRATOR
```

These are not the only examples of Aerious Words™, many more exist.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Aerious Words™ are ...

> words in which vowels appear in monotonically increasing order - that is, in an Aerious Word™, a vowel earlier in the sequence ***A, E, I, O, U*** never follows one later in that sequence.

They are **Aerious Words™** because

> ***AE**R**IOU**S* contains all 5 vowels in order.

Comment: Uuh, how did I not get that...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7XVcqZodAM&t=5

Comment: Correct! Great job!

Comment: @OliverNi *aerious* is an aerious word